# Next JS with react-redux HOC typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, next.js

I've been trying to get the types correct for a HOC that wraps most of the Next pages but I can't seem to get rid of all the type errors.

With the current code, I am getting a type error on the `connect` function which I haven't been able to resolve for awhile.

I'm assuming that I may have the Component type inside the `PageWrapper` component done incorrectly?

```js
Argument of type 'ConnectedComponent<typeof HomePage, Pick<(ClassAttributes<HomePage> & ComponentClass<{}, any> & { getInitialProps?(context: NextPageContext<any, AnyAction>): {} | Promise<...>; } & IStateProps) | (ClassAttributes<...> & ... 2 more ... & IStateProps), "ref" | ... 5 more ... | "key">>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(ComponentClass<{}, any> & { getInitialProps?(context: NextPageContext<any, AnyAction>): {} | Promise<{}>; }) | (FunctionComponent<...> & { ...; }) | (ComponentClass<...> & ... 1 more ... & { ...; }) | (FunctionComponent<...> & ... 1 more ... & { ...; })'.
  Type 'ConnectedComponent<typeof HomePage, Pick<(ClassAttributes<HomePage> & ComponentClass<{}, any> & { getInitialProps?(context: NextPageContext<any, AnyAction>): {} | Promise<...>; } & IStateProps) | (ClassAttributes<...> & ... 2 more ... & IStateProps), "ref" | ... 5 more ... | "key">>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}> & { getInitialProps?(context: NextPageContext<any, AnyAction>): {} | Promise<{}>; }'.
    Type 'ConnectedComponent<typeof HomePage, Pick<(ClassAttributes<HomePage> & ComponentClass<{}, any> & { getInitialProps?(context: NextPageContext<any, AnyAction>): {} | Promise<...>; } & IStateProps) | (ClassAttributes<...> & ... 2 more ... & IStateProps), "ref" | ... 5 more ... | "key">>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
      Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
        Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' has no properties in common with type 'Pick<(ClassAttributes<HomePage> & ComponentClass<{}, any> & { getInitialProps?(context: NextPageContext<any, AnyAction>): {} | Promise<...>; } & IStateProps) | (ClassAttributes<...> & ... 2 more ... & IStateProps), "ref" | ... 5 more ... | "key">'.ts(2345)
```

**HomePage.tsx**

```js
import Layout from 'components/Layout'
import PageWrapper from 'components/PageWrapper'
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { IContactState } from 'redux/contact/reducer'
import { IApplicationState } from 'redux/store'

interface IStateProps {
  contact: IContactState
}

class HomePage extends React.Component<NextPage & IStateProps> {
  render() {
    const { contact } = this.props

    return (
      <Layout title="Dashboard">
        <section className="dashboard-wrapper">
          <div className="dashboard">
            <h1>Welcome {contact.firstName}</h1>
          </div>
        </section>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: IApplicationState): IStateProps => ({
  contact: state.contact
})

export default PageWrapper(connect(mapStateToProps)(HomePage))
```

**PageWrapper.tsx**

```js
import { NextComponentType, NextPageContext } from 'next'
import React from 'react'

const PageWrapper = (Component: React.ComponentType & NextComponentType) => (
  class extends React.Component<NextComponentType> {
    static async getInitialProps (ctx: NextPageContext) {

      return {
        ...(Component.getInitialProps ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx) : undefined),
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Component {...this.props} />
      )
    }
  }
)

export default PageWrapper
```

Comment: your `PageWrapper` does not expect a `ConnectedComponent` (from `react-redux`) it seems. either fix this in `PageWrapper` by changing the argument types or chain it `HomePage` -> `PageWrapper` -> `connect`. personally think the second solution is cleaner.

Comment: @bbortt but that means I would have to fetch the whole state and pass it down as I won't know whether the child component will use one reducer or more. I've tried changing the `PageWrapper` to take in `ConnectedComponent` but there is a different type issue when returning the child component. `'{ propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<{}> | undefined; contextType?: Context<any> | undefined; contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any> | undefined; ... 6 more ...; children?: ReactNode; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'`

Comment: Ahm no.. state of `connect` is mapped into props and you're passing all props anyways (that's what a HOC normaly does): `return ( <Component {...this.props} /> )`.

Comment: Hmm either way, it seems like the `PageWrapper` needs to know what the prop types are for it to work without errors...